# Riddle Number Five

Tags: riddle, cipher

I feel as if my challenges are a bit too extreme for many, so here is a more simpler conundrum to solve. The cipher used is the same as the answer to this riddle:

> When is a cipher like a person who never cheats?

Here is the key that will help decrypt the encoded message. I'd advise that you read between the lines on this one:

> 1) When is a chicken's baby like a genius?
>
> 2) What does a god and a planet have in common?
>
> 3) I'm cold hearted, yet melt under pressure. What am I?
>
> 4) When is an elder like a crisp wafer?
>
> 5) When is a target like a spot on the wall?
>
> 6) What goes up, yet never comes down?

As for the encrypted message, it is not a riddle that you must solve. Instead, just decipher the code and claim victory! That's about it this time. Here is the message for you to decipher:

> DLIMQBUQHCSGKGT XPTEA TLHXGA QON QGCCOIQ BEP PIATWOUGA GZ DLAG VNTT OTIN

Good luck everyone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**SOLUTION:**

The key is:

> ENIGMA

The cipher is:

> Playfair (Person who never cheats = Play Fair)

and the decrypted message  is:

> CONGRATULATIONS YOUVE SOLVED THE RIDDLES AND DECRYPTED MY CODE WELL DONE

explanation:

> You need to take the first letter of each answer

1) When is a chicken's baby like a genius?

> Einstein (there's a toy called baby Einstein who is a chicken, and einstein was also a genius)

2) What does a god and a planet have in common?

> Name (netptune, jupiter, mars, pluto etc are names of both gods and planets)

3) I'm cold hearted, yet melt under pressure. What am I?

> Ice (Ice is cold and melts under pressure)

4) When is an elder like a crisp wafer?

> Gingerbread (The gingerbread man is a crisp wafer in the shape of an old man)

5) When is a target like a spot on the wall?

> Mark (mark and target are synonyms, a mark is also a spot on the wall)

6) What goes up, yet never comes down?

> Age (age can only increase, not decrease)

Next step:

> Taking the first letter of each answer we get --> **enigma**

Finally, I used [this](http://rumkin.com/tools/cipher/playfair.php) site to decrypt the message.

Comment: And with that, we have a winner! Congrats to you, Pirate!

Answer (score 1):

Partial:

When is a cipher like a person who never cheats?

> Playfair

Guesses for the Key (clearly, some are incorrect at this time)

1) When is a chicken's baby like a genius?

> <s>Never</s>

2) What does a god and a planet have in common?

> <s>Nothing</s>
>  a **name**. Roman mythology iirc.

3) I'm cold hearted, yet melt under pressure. What am I?

> <s>Facade</s>

4) When is an elder like a crisp wafer?

> **Thin** <s>/ Stale</s>

5) When is a target like a spot on the wall?

> Laser (pointer)

6) What goes up, yet never comes down?

> Age. Although, many answers available.

Theoretically:

> The total character length when the answers are combined should be 25.

Also

> The answers should not share characters with any other answer right? So somehow, we're to get 6 answers with only 5 (sometimes 6) vowels?

Total shot in the dark, but:

> I think some of the encrypted words are:
>  congratulations
>  answer
>  code

Comment: Well, the answer to the cipher riddle is correct. It is a Playfair cipher that I used. However, all but one answer to the key riddles are incorrect.

Comment: Is the key a keyword + filler, or actually all 6 answers combined?

Comment: Good question! Indeed, it is a keyword, created by the 6 answers combined. The clue I'll give is read between the lines :D